# JPA - CascadeType.REMOVE após entidade ser excluída por orphanRemoval=true

Tags: java, jpa

```
public class PrimeiroNivel {  

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="primeiroNivel", orphanRemoval=true)  
   private List<SegundoNivel> niveisSecundarios;  
}

public class SegundoNivel {  

    @JoinColumn(name="primeirNivel")
    @ManyToOne  
    private PrimeiroNivel primeiroNivel;  

    @JoinColumn(name="outraClasse")
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})  
    private OutraClasse outraClasse;
}

public class OutraClasse {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="outraClasse")  
    private List<SegundoNivel> segundosNiveis;
}
```

Considerando as classes e anotações acima:

```
instanciaDePrimeiroNivel.setNiveisSecundarios(null);
```

Alguém sabe por que a linha acima exclui os níveis secundários que estavam presentes na lista da instanciaDePrimeiroNivel (comportamento esperado do orphanRemoval), mas não exclui as instâncias de OutraClasse associadas nesses níveis excluídos (as quais estão marcadas para exclusão em cascata)?

CascadeType.REMOVE não funciona se não utilizar o entityManager.remove(Object)?

Há alguma solução alternativa para resolver essa situação?